# Same environment(jenkins node), slower executable jar

Tags: java, jenkins, executable-jar

I have set up a new node in Jenkins. 
Except for the server specifications, everything else is the same, but it takes twice as much execution speed on the new node server. 
Has anyone ever experienced this? I need help.

|  | Old Node | New Node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server Spec | 4vCPU, 8GB Mem | 8vCPU, 16GB Mem |
| JDK | 1.8.0_161 OpenJDK | 1.8.0_161 OpenJDK |
| Jar | same | same |
| Jar execute option(e.g. `-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m` and etc...) | same | same |
| Build time | **7 min** | **13 min** |

Comment: Well, this *can* be caused by the application itself - for example, if the number of threads depends on the number of available cores, but synchronisation overhead drowns out the benefits even for a small number of threads - this obviously depends on what the application does.

Comment: Not to mention that there are all other sorts of specs that could matter.

Comment: Sometimes, providing more memory can also slow things down (GC overhead slowly increases with size of managed memory, etc. some things that fail quickly with little memory take longer to fail with more memory, and lots of other effects).

Comment: You do not provide enough information in your question. What do you execute exactly and which CPUs do you use? If your code is single-threaded the number of CPU cores is irrelevant, if your code is IO bound the spec of your storage or even network speed may be more relevant. Depending on what you execute the access times of your memory may be more relevant than its size ...

Comment: I note you said "vCPU" rather than CPU.  Note that the performance of a "vCPU" depends on how busy the compute node is, and depends on whatever other virtual servers may be doing on the compute node.  It could also depend on how busy the server's disk back-end is.  In short, you should be talking to your cloud computing provider ....

Comment: Hello everyone. Sorry for the late comment. I've compared all the server setting in 
 old node server with new server, and I find out ssh config was set in the old server: `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. So I added the setting on the new node server, and the job runs in time as I expected. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late comment.

I've compared all the server setting in old node server with new server, and I find out ssh config was set in the old server: `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.

So I added the setting on the new node server, and the job runs in time as I expected.

Thank you for all.